# Slow down Mongo using Nifi with replicas

Tags: mongodb, apache, apache-nifi

Hi!

I'm getting poor performance after a few time using Apache Nifi with Mongo in replica. It's being very strange, because, when we start the replicas and Nifi processor, it goes so fast. After a few time it slows down so much.

The Nifi processor configuration is which you can see in the image.

[Nifi Processor Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ITTM.png)

Because of this issue I get a heavy bottleneck ... any ideas ?

[Bottleneck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRAZA.png)

Comment: did you check mem/cpu/io usage on machines where nifi and mongo are running?

Comment: It's possible to insert thousands of docs with no problem from a node script.

Also, if i reboot Mongo machines, at the beginning it can insert so fast, but after some time ... it slows down

Answer (score 0):

Finally I changed write concern at nifi processor and now it runs better.

Comment: hi! I know it's been a while since this answer, please explain which property or what config you had updated for this?